# Search box missing Woocommerce Product Bundle Extension

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

It should be a search box, instead of a drop-down box. Can anybody let me know what I will need to do to get the search box here?

I will highly appreciate your help. Thank in advance.

Please check the screenshot to get the idea:

[image]

https://snag.gy/VridhP.jpg

Comment: As asked, you will get better assistance if you direct this through the support channels of the plugin's developer. There's is no way to guess the intended or incorrect functionality. This forum does not handle _questions concerning third party plugins and themes._: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

Product bundle uses `select2` jQuery add on to enable search with select drop down.

Since it doesn't work it's some problem with jQuery. Look for JS error in your console. And check for any conflicting plugins.

Comment: BadgeOS was causing the conflict.

Comment: Never worked with that plugin. Contact plugin support or if the plugin is not necessary, get rid of it.